# Does android use database to store the information of ringtone?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

As the title indicates, does android use database to store the meta information of ringtone?
like the path of ringtones. Otherwise, how could RingtoneManager.getCursor() return a Cursor pointing to all ringtone ?

PS, how to write a ContentProvider for files, e.g., ringtone? I see so many examples only talk
about how to deal with database, but none of them are dealing with files. One method I can come out is using database to store the path of files, then manipulate the files with the path.

Comment: If the files are on external storage, or not in a resource, then storing the path in a database makes sense, so why not go for what may be a good approach and not worry how others do it.

Comment: @JamesBlack, thanks. I just want to know what is the common way to create a contentprovider for files. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard content providers for audio media:

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

The table column `IS_RINGTONE` marks those used as a ringtone.

Ref.: [android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html)